# Showing if something is a consistent estimator?

Tags: descriptive-statistics, distributions

I have a cont random variable $X$ which has exponential distribution with mean $\theta$ of $X_1,X_2,...,X_n$

let $Y = \ln{X}$

and I've found that
$$E(\ln X)=\int_0^\infty \ln x\cdot\left(\frac{1}{\theta} e^{-x/\theta}\right)\,dx.$$
Let $x=u\theta$. Then $\ln(x)=\ln\theta+\ln u$ and our integral becomes
$$\int_0^\infty (\ln\theta) e^{-u}\,du +\int_0^\infty (\ln x)e^{-x}\,dx.$$

---

Letting $Y_1,Y_2,...,Y_n$ being a random sample of $X$ , how can I show that $\bar Y$ is NOT a consistent estimator of $\ln (\theta)$ ?

Comment: Please add the `[self-study]` tag & read its 
[wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info).

Comment: It looks like you've shown that $E[\ln Y] \neq \theta$ correct? Then by WLLN, $\bar{Y}_n \xrightarrow{p} E[Y]$.